# Почему не генерируется R.java?

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Когда создаю новый проект в Eclipse, в нём отсутствует R.java, хотя должен генерироваться автоматически, на сколько я понимаю. Если сразу после создания сделать clean, то он появляется. В чём может причина такого поведения Eclipse и вообще в нём ли дело?

Comment: не совсем в тему вопроса, но я пользуюсь IntelliJ IDEA и  там не возникало еще такой ситуации, пользовался Eclipse только первые две недели, когда начал писать код, да и там есть много различных плюшек от jet brains, которые знают свое дело :)
Так что советую переходить туда, переходи займет некоторое время, но оно того стоит. 
PS. Ответ ниже должен решить проблему :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.java` генерируется в процессе сборки проекта.
Можно проверить две опции:

- Проект>Собирать автоматически
- Проект>Очистить>Запускать сборку автоматически

Первая, мягко говоря, непредсказуема. Я ее обычно отключаю и собираю проект явно. 
Использовать или не использовать вторую зависит больше от привычки.
И, понятно, при ошибках в xml R генерироваться не будет(в новом проекте, с xml проблем быть не должно).

Comment: Аня, спасибо за объяснения! Когда делаю clean, то папка gen в проекте оказывается вообще пустая. Перерыла все настройки, не генерируется R.java, хотя в xml ошибок нет, только в java файлах из-за того что R.id. не найдены. Создавать проект заново или всё-таки этот можно реанимировать? Во вкладке Project следующие варианты доступны: Build all, Build project, Build working set, Clean, Build automatically, Generete JavaCod и Properties.

Comment: Build project должно сработать. Если нет, убери все галочки автоматической сборки, сделай clean, а потом опять Build project.

Answer (score 2):

**Решение:** в комплект adt уже входит Eclipse. Распаковываете SDK там 2 папки и SDK менеджер. Вот одна папка как раз с Eclipse, уже настроенный, там все работает. Так сказать, примечание к инструкции по установке.

Comment: та же проблема, но как раз с adt-bundle, только поставил. в новых проектах r.java отсутствует, а в старых r.java есть, конечно, но не модифицируется. eclipse + adt стоял давно, все было нормально. спасибо за советы, завтра проверю!

Answer (score 1):

Такая проблема возникает, если Eclipse теряет SDK.
Что надо:

1. проверить путь к SDK: Window -> Preferences, слева выбрать Android, затем справа путь указать к корневой папке SDK
2. запустить SDK Manager и обновить Tools: верхний пункт в списке, обновить в нем Android SDK Tools, Android Platform-tools и Android SDK Build-tools
3. возможно, обновить Eclipse (ADT Bundle, Android IDE - кто что использует): Help -> Check for updates
4. собираем проект - все ОК, R.java на месте, ресурсы в нем описываются автоматом и т.п., как и должно быть. Если все же нет и R.java нет на месте, то п.5
5. создать пустой файл R.java в gen/<package>  и опять Build Project

Answer (score 0):

Короче народ, тоже долго мучился, читал английские манускрипты американских друидов-шаманов, ТИПА шарящих в андроид-коде, помогло вот что:
в файле res/values/**strings.xml** есть две строчки по-умолчанию:

`<string name="app_name">Name</string>`

`<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>`

если их удалить или изменить - **R.jawa** начинает страдать фигнёй. Эти параметры связаны с **AndroidManifest.xml** и чем-то ещё (найдёте сами, так как я поспешил поделиться этой прекрасной новостью и не стал вдаваться в подробности).

Ну и да, необходимо поставить проект на АвтоБилд:
**Project** > **Build Atomatically**
После сделайте Чистку:
**Project** > **Clean...**

Answer (score 0):

Перерыл множество сайтов, ничего не помогало, вроде решилась проблема так:
В AndroidManifest.xml показывал ошибку в Theme, просто через Aplication стер AppTheme, после этого R.java сразу сгенерировался и все запустилось. Проверяйте xml на ошибки. Удачи ;)